# Cannot convert from IQueryable <decimal,Project1,Model> to IQueryable<Project1,Model>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What does this error mean?

My error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<decimal,Project1.Domain.Models.DepartmentBreakdownReport>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Project1.Domain.Models.DepartmentBreakdownReport>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I would like to know what it is in order for me to be able to fix it. It only happens when I add a LINQ GroupBy onto my results.

```
 public IQueryable<DepartmentBreakdownReport> GetDepartmentBreakdownBySupplierIDAndReviewID(int ClientID, int? SupplierID, int? ReviewID) {
            return (from d in Db.Details
                    join h in Db.Headers
                    on new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID }
                    equals new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
                    where d.ClientID == ClientID && h.SupplierID == SupplierID

                    join sd in Db.SuppDepts
                    on new { a = d.ClientID, b = d.CategoryID ?? 0 }
                    equals new { a = sd.ClientID, b = sd.CategoryID }

                    join r in Db.Reviews
                    on new { h.ClientID, h.ReviewID }
                    equals new { r.ClientID, r.ReviewID }

                    join rp in Db.ReviewPeriods
                    on new { a = r.ClientID, b = r.ReviewPeriodID ?? 0 }
                    equals new { a = rp.ClientID, b = rp.ReviewPeriodID }
                    where r.ReviewID == ReviewID

                    join su in Db.Suppliers
                   on new { h.ClientID, h.SupplierID }
               equals new { su.ClientID, su.SupplierID }

                    select new DepartmentBreakdownReport {
                        DepartmentName = sd.DepartmentName,
                        SumOfAmount = d.Amount,
                        SupplierID = h.SupplierID,
                        ReviewID = h.ReviewID,
                        ReviewName = rp.ReviewPeriodName,
                        SupplierName = su.SupplierName,
                        ClientID = d.ClientID
                    }).GroupBy(r=>r.Amount);
        }
```

Comment: Your function ends in a `GroupBy` which will return an `IGrouping` keyed by amount, each group has an enumerable of `DepartmentBreakdownReport`, which doesn't match your return type. `GroupBy` on an `Amount` would be very strange as this would generally be a continuous value.

Comment: one Trick I like to do, is right click on a portion of the code, and then go to __refactor -> extract method__ to see what type comes out

Comment: In order to get a method that returns the query, you probably want to do something like `var a = [insert query here]; var b = a;, and then extract the first line to the method

Comment: `GroupBy` creates an `IGrouping` that includes a key value and the data as a sub-collection.  What are you expecting to return?  What does grouping so for you?

Comment: @DStanley I'm trying to group and order by amount. It makes my results look much more presentable.

Comment: By "group" you mean "have all records together"?  That's _sorting_, not _grouping_ (in set terms).  Grouping is "combine all records into one"

Comment: @DStanley I need to do both :)

Comment: @AndrewKilburn That's not possible - Suppose you have 4 DOG and 3 CAT records in "random" order.  With Sorting you get the 4 DOG records consecutively and 3 CAT records consecutively, so 7 records total.  With grouping you get one DOG record and one CAT record.  Which are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does this error mean?

Your return type is `IQueryable<DepartmentBreakdownReport>` yet you are attempting to return a `IGrouping<decimal,Project1.Domain.Models.DepartmentBreakdownReport>`

When you call `.GroupBy` you change the return type to `IGrouping` rather than `IQueryable`, it also introduces the decimal as part of the IGrouping expression (Which is the amount variable you are grouping by).

To fix it you can simply change the method signature to:

```
public IGrouping<decimal,Project1.Domain.Models.DepartmentBreakdownReport> GetDepartmentBreakdownBySupplierIDAndReviewID(int ClientID, int? SupplierID, int? ReviewID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the error. I cannot change it to IGrouping though as other parts of my program requires it to use a IOrderedQueryable. I appreciate the explanation a lot. I'm trying to learn the meaning of error messages so I can have a better chance of solving them

Comment: @AndrewKilburn - okay I would recommend removing the .GroupBy from the LINQ query, create a new method which takes in the IQueryable as a parameter and then handle the GroupBy in the new method.  This way the original method conforms to the name and the new method would be smaller, concise and more testable.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the method name `GetDepartmentBreakdownBySupplierIDAndReviewID` would imply:

- Firstly that the method return type would be something like this, assuming types of int for `SupplierId` and `ReviewId` :

```
IGrouping<Tuple<int, int>, IQueryable<DepartmentBreakdownReport>> 
                                       GetDepartmentBreakdownBySupplierIDAndReviewID(...)
```

- Secondly that the return should be on a final projection something like:

```
select new DepartmentBreakdownReport { ... })
    .GroupBy(r => new Tuple<int, int>(r.SupplierID, r.ReviewID));
```